# Scale font in TikZ plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I have a lot (~100) of TikZ plots, autogenerated with a [popular matlab script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022).

I want to resize the font of the plots, because it is currently too large.
I googled a bit, and found some answers (even from this stackexchange). None of them seems to apply to my case.

I have tried `\scalefont` and `\small` so far.

A typical `.tikz` file is like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
     width=\figurewidth,
     height=\figureheight,
     scale only axis,
     xmin=0.6,
     xmax=1.4,
     xlabel={$\text{S/S}_{\text{mindrag}}$},
     ymin=74000,
     ymax=94000,
     ylabel={b},
     title={$\text{M}_{\text{des}}\text{ =0.77 AR =9.3}$}
   ]
  % Tons of lines...
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

What I have is:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_1_1.tikz}}
  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_1_3.tikz}}
  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_1_5.tikz}}\\

  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_3_1.tikz}}
  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_3_3.tikz}}
  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_3_5.tikz}}\\

  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_5_1.tikz}}
  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_5_3.tikz}}
  \subfloat{\input{plots/WTO_plot_5_5.tikz}}\\

  \caption{MTOW}
  \label{figs}
\end{figure}
```

I am looking for a "global" solution, one which does not need to edit every single file.

Comment: Probably `\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={font=\tiny}}`?

Comment: @TomBombadil thanks for the answer, but it does not seems to work. Atm I've fixed it by rescaling the graphs (so that the characters don't overlap each other).

Comment: That was a close guess. At least for me it works with `\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={font=\tiny}}`.